# Scala pattern match with varargs

Tags: scala

I've a web server to handle incoming requests. Based on the http method and endpoint I process requests differently. Currently the code handles it:

```
def routes: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = { httpRequest: HttpRequest =>
    (httpRequest.method, httpRequest.uri.path.toString) match {
      case (GET, "/login") =>
         process(getLogin)

      case (POST, "/newUser") =>
        process(createNewUser)   

      ..
```

But now I need to support a bunch of related endpoints of this form:

```
/{version}/{serviceName}
```

For example:

```
/0/userService
/0/bookService
```

So I want to update existing code to support the new endpoints:

```
case (POST, "/${version}/${service}) => 
        if ($version == 0 && $service.equalToIgnoreCase("userService")) 
            process(user service)       

        if ($version == 0 && $service.equalToIgnoreCase("bookService"))     
            process(book service)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest using a web framework such as Akka HTTP which provide various ways of doing this that are likely to be more robust than a hand-crafted version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
val UrlPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = """/(.*)/(.*)""".r
val path = "/0/userService"  

path match {
    case UrlPattern(version, service) => println(version, version)
}
```

The code above will result in:

```
(0, userService)
```

being printed to the console, but you can to whatever you want with the variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
val v0Services = (s: String) => s.toLowerCase match {
    case "userservice" => userServiceV0()
    case "bookservice" => bookServiceV0()
}
val v1Services = (s: String) => s.toLowerCase match {
    case "userservice" => userServiceV1()
    case "bookservice" => bookServiceV1()
}
val check = (v: String) => v match {
    case "0" => v0Services
    case "1" => v1Services
}



case (POST, "/${version}/${service}) => check(version)(service)
```